# How to compile tensorflow c_api using Makefile in linux

Tags: c++, c, linux, tensorflow, makefile

I'm trying to compile tensorflow c_api using Makefile. I need help to add the tensorflow libraries in the makefile. I'm running it on Ubuntu.

Here I have attached the folder structure of the project,
[folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ydg5Q.png)

I have also added the Makefile below.

```
CC = g++
CFLAGS = -c -Wall
INCLUDES = -I "tensorflow/c"

LIBS =-L "lib" -ltensorflow -ltensorflow_framework
all : exec

exec : simple.o
    $(CC) -o exec simple.o $(INCLUDES) $(LIBS)

.cpp.o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< 

clean: 
    rm -rf *.
```

The program compiles without error,

> g++ -c -Wall simple.cpp
>
> g++ -o exec simple.o -I "tensorflow/c" -L "lib" -ltensorflow -ltensorflow_framework

but when i run the exec I get the following error,

> ./exec: error while loading shared libraries: libtensorflow.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to make sure that `lib` is on `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=`pwd`/lib:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}
./exec
```

Comment: Cool :) Have fun :)